# How to do with NullPointer exetpion in retrofit

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception, retrofit

I have problem with null pointer exception. 2 days i can't do anything. help me please. NullPointer at line. Here is a problem but I dont know how to do.

```
        for (AsanaPOJO a : asanas.getAsanas()) {
            Log.d("AsanaPROGRAM LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + a.getName());
        }
```

here is JSON:

```
{

    "asanas": 

[

{

    "id": 34,
    "name": "Easy Pranayama",
    "imgLarge": "/system/photos/asanas/34/large/34.jpg",
    "imgThumb": "/system/photos/asanas/34/thumb/34.jpg",
    "level_id": 1,
    "type_id": 9,
    "audio": "/system/audios/asanas/34/body/en/34.mp3",
    "title_audio": "/system/audios/asanas/34/title/en/34.mp3",
    "duration": 69,
    "fullDesc": "Lie down comfortably on your back so that your abdominal muscles are relaxed. Close your eyes.",
    "photo": "/system/photos/asanas/34/original/34.jpg",
    "sanskrit_name": "Sahaj Pranayama ",
    "sanskrit_audio_title": "/sanskrit_audio_titles/original/missing.png",
    "breathing_video": "/system/videos/asanas/34/breathing/34.mp4",
    "is_paid": false,
    "is_breathing": true,
    "old_identifier": "331",
    "old_pk": 772

},
{

    "id": 35,
    "name": "Easy Pranayama Advanced",
    "imgLarge": "/system/photos/asanas/35/large/35.jpg",
    "imgThumb": "/system/photos/asanas/35/thumb/35.jpg",
    "level_id": 2,
    "type_id": 9,
    "audio": "/system/audios/asanas/35/body/en/35.mp3",
    "title_audio": "/system/audios/asanas/35/title/en/35.mp3",
    "duration": 92,
    "fullDesc": "Lie down comfortably on your back so that your abdominal muscles are relaxed. Close your eyes. Bring your hands behind your head.",
    "photo": "/system/photos/asanas/35/original/35.jpg",
    "sanskrit_name": "Sahaj Pranayama Advanced",
    "sanskrit_audio_title": "/sanskrit_audio_titles/original/missing.png",
    "breathing_video": "/system/videos/asanas/35/breathing/35.mp4",
    "is_paid": true,
    "is_breathing": true,
    "old_identifier": "332",
    "old_pk": 773

}
    ]

}
```

here is Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MYApi myapi = (MYApi) new Builder().setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(MYurl.BASE_URL).build().create(MYApi.class);


    myapi.getAsanas(new Callback<Asanas>() {
        public void success(Asanas asanas,Response response) {


            for (AsanaPOJO a : asanas.getAsanas()) {
                Log.d("AsanaPROGRAM LOGS", BuildConfig.FLAVOR + a.getName());
            }

        }

        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        }
    });



}
```

Class Asanas:

```
public class Asanas {

private List<AsanaPOJO> asanaPOJOs;

public Asanas() {
}

public List<AsanaPOJO> getAsanas ()
{
    return this.asanaPOJOs;
}

public void setAsanas (List<AsanaPOJO> asanas)
{
    this.asanaPOJOs = asanaPOJOs;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [asanas = "+asanaPOJOs+"]";
}
}
```

Class AsanaPOJO

```
public class AsanaPOJO {

private int id;
private String name;
private String imgLarge;
private String imgThumb;
private int level_id;
private int type_id;
private String audio;
private String title_audio;
private int duration;
private String fullDesc;
private String photo;
private String sanskrit_name;
private String sanskrit_audio_title;
private String breathing_video;
private String is_paid;
private String is_breathing;
private int old_identifier;
private int old_pk;

public AsanaPOJO() {
}

public String getSanskrit_audio_title ()
{
    return sanskrit_audio_title;
}

public void setSanskrit_audio_title (String sanskrit_audio_title)
{
    this.sanskrit_audio_title = sanskrit_audio_title;
}

public String getAudio ()
{
    return audio;
}

public void setAudio (String audio)
{
    this.audio = audio;
}

public String getImgThumb ()
{
    return imgThumb;
}

public void setImgThumb (String imgThumb)
{
    this.imgThumb = imgThumb;
}

public String getFullDesc ()
{
    return fullDesc;
}

public void setFullDesc (String fullDesc)
{
    this.fullDesc = fullDesc;
}

public String getImgLarge ()
{
    return imgLarge;
}

public void setImgLarge (String imgLarge)
{
    this.imgLarge = imgLarge;
}

public int getLevel_id ()
{
    return level_id;
}

public void setLevel_id (int level_id)
{
    this.level_id = level_id;
}

public String getPhoto ()
{
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto (String photo)
{
    this.photo = photo;
}

public int getType_id ()
{
    return type_id;
}

public void setType_id (int type_id)
{
    this.type_id = type_id;
}

public int getOld_pk ()
{
    return old_pk;
}

public void setOld_pk (int old_pk)
{
    this.old_pk = old_pk;
}

public int getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public int getDuration ()
{
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration (int duration)
{
    this.duration = duration;
}

public String getTitle_audio ()
{
    return title_audio;
}

public void setTitle_audio (String title_audio)
{
    this.title_audio = title_audio;
}

public String getIs_breathing ()
{
    return is_breathing;
}

public void setIs_breathing (String is_breathing)
{
    this.is_breathing = is_breathing;
}

public String getName ()
{
    return name;
}

public void setName (String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public int getOld_identifier ()
{
    return old_identifier;
}

public void setOld_identifier (int old_identifier)
{
    this.old_identifier = old_identifier;
}

public String getIs_paid ()
{
    return is_paid;
}

public void setIs_paid (String is_paid)
{
    this.is_paid = is_paid;
}

public String getSanskrit_name ()
{
    return sanskrit_name;
}

public void setSanskrit_name (String sanskrit_name)
{
    this.sanskrit_name = sanskrit_name;
}

public String getBreathing_video ()
{
    return breathing_video;
}

public void setBreathing_video (String breathing_video)
{
    this.breathing_video = breathing_video;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Asana"+name+","+"id";


}

public int checkBool(String s){
    if (s.equals("true")){
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}


}
```

Interface for Retrofit

```
public interface MYApi {
@GET("/asanas")
void getAsanas(Callback<Asanas> response);
}
```

And LOG:

```
"is_paid":true,"is_breathing":false,"old_identifier":"248","old_pk":1044}]}
09-24 12:06:16.049  20971-20998/com.example.user.asanasproject D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (261559-byte body)
09-24 12:06:16.539  20971-20971/com.example.user.asanasproject D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-24 12:06:16.539  20971-20971/com.example.user.asanasproject W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c0aa68)
09-24 12:06:16.539  20971-20971/com.example.user.asanasproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.user.asanasproject.MainActivity$1.success(MainActivity.java:37)
            at com.example.user.asanasproject.MainActivity$1.success(MainActivity.java:27)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks at your JSON response, fields `is_paid` and `is_breathing` are boolean, but in your class `AsanaPOJO` you declare them as `String`.

Try changing them to boolean value.

**EDIT:**

Also what @NaviRamyle said - your `Asanas` class ArrayList variables name does not match the JSON response.

Comment: now it's OK. thanks, but for each not works i can't work with List...  i haven't any errors or exceptions just for each not work.(

Comment: How do you mean it does not work? Do you get any Logs? Print out the length of the arrayList to see if something is inside, or better step through the code with a debugger.

Comment: No , I have no logs , it looks like it works. But all that is in the method of success is not met, no matter what to write. Debugger does not work because I check application on the phone, turn on the debugger and all has crash

Answer (score 1):

Change `private List<AsanaPOJO> asanaPOJOs;` to `private List<AsanaPOJO> asanas;`

Model variable name must be exactly as the JSON key name

```
{
    "asanas": [..]
}
```